# Как передать custom Objects сохраненные через NSUserdefaults в ячейку таблицы?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

Разбор сохранения(Сохранение сложных массивов значений через NSUserDefaults). Теперь необходимо сохраненые элементы на одном контроллере передать в создаваемую вместе с этими элементами ячейку на другой контроллер,на которой отображается только лэйбл с названием ячейки, по нажатию на которую переходим на третий контроллер в котором отображается таблица из ячеек с сохраненными элементами. При создании новых ячеек сохраняем для них новый список из выбранных элементов
Сохранение в 1 контроллере

```
        workout.append(self.nameWorkoutTextField.text!)//текст получаем из текстфилда
        self.nameWorkoutTextField.text = ""
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(workout, forKey: "workout")//создаем название ячейки

        let data: NSData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(exersise) //Сохранение выбранных элементов 
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(data, forKey: "Exersise")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

Загрузка(сохранение) во втором контроллере в отдельную ячейку

```
var workout = [String]()//вынесен за класс контроллера

  override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  //читаем название ячейки
    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("workout") != nil {
    workout = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("workout") as! [String]
}
    //читаем выбранные элементы для ячейки
    let newData: NSData = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Exersise") as! NSData
    let newExersise: Array = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(newData) as! [Exersise]
    var exersiseIndex: Exersise = newExersise[............???]
```

Отображаем ячейку

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
   myCell.textLabel?.text = workout[indexPath.row]
   return myCell
}
```

Передача всех элементов этой ячейки на третий контроллер по нажатию на ячейку

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "To3Controller" {
        let viewController = ((segue.destinationViewController) as! MyWorkoutExersiseViewController)
        let indexPath = self.workoutTableView!.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        //дальше код не правильный
        let exersise = newExersise[indexPath.row]
        viewController.exersiseFor3Control = exersise
    }
}
```

В третьем контроллере отображаем список из ячеек со всеми элементами

```
var exersiseFor3Control: [Exersise]()
```

Отображение в ячейках элементов

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    //дальше код скорее всего тож не правильный
    myCell.textLabel?.text = exersiseFor3Control[indexPath.row].name
    myCell.imageView!.image = UIImage(named:exersiseFor3Control[indexPath.row].image)
    return myCell
}
```

Comment: Могли бы мое творчество переименовать во что-то более нормальное, а не использовать `newArr` `newData` и `newObject`.

Comment: я так понимаю, вам надо загруженные значение сохранять в переменной инстанса. Когда вы пытаетесь сделать `let exersise = newObject[indexPath.row]` у вас переменной `newObject` уже нет.

Comment: Кстати если при чтении не прописать if ... !nil то, если ничего не сохранено, апп падает, а если прописываешь, то newDate, newExersise, exersiseIndex за пределами этого оператора выдают ошибку о недоступности